# Jenkins android emulator plugin fails to find AVD path

Tags: android, linux, jenkins

I have an Android project in Jenkins. My server is a Windows 2008 and the slave where I'm trying to run the build is a headless Ubuntu 14.04.

I have setup the `ANDROID_HOME` as `"/opt/android-sdk-linux/"` but when the emulator tries to run the ADB server (which I have tested manually in the console) it tries to complete the `ANDROID_HOME` path to `"tools"` with `'\'` instead of `'/'`. e.g: `/opt/android-sdk-linux/\platform-tools\adb`

I can't find a way to tell the plugin that it's running on a linux. The Android SDK is only installed in the slave. I would need permission in my company to install it in the main integration server, but I can do it if there is no other way.

How can I tell the Android plugin that it's running in Linux?

Comment: Looks like a regression in Jenkins: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-23134

Comment: So i will have to install the sdk in the server where the plugin is installed right?.

Comment: Yes either run the Android job on your Windows master, or attempt to recompile jenkins with a hard-coded separator on your ubuntu machine(s). Or, wait until the Jenkins team resolves it :)

Comment: I'll talk with my superiors and i'll go for the server installation. Thanks for giving me that link :)

Answer (score 1):

As of 9/8/2014, this appears to be a regression in Jenkins related to how it builds paths on slaves, and how that can fail when you have differing path separators between your Master and Slave(s).

Here's the relevant Jenkins issue: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-23134

The solution(s) for now seem to only be:

1. Run the job on your Master
2. Roll back to Jenkins 2.10
3. Manually tweak Jenkins yourself to fix the issue, here's a sample: